# Facebook Failed Binder Transaction - Hashkey or Bundle issue

Tags: android, facebook, bundle

I am having trouble using multiple testers to test my Android app with Facebook integration. I generated a hashkey for myself and I am able to use my app properly. But when the testers download the app they do not appear in the apps Facebook Friends list. After debugging I noticed it says `!!! Failed Binder Transaction !!!` in the logcat -- But this error only occurs on the Testers device, not my device.

Many people have suggested it's a hashkey issue.

Does each tester need his own unique Facebook hashkey? Or can they all test my app using my hashkey?

I generated the hashkey using the keytool commmand line option. Perhaps it is better to use Facebook's other option of generating a hashkey using code in the MainActivity. Suggestions?

Other users said Failed Binder Transaction can occur when you pass data into a bundle since there are size limitations. I suspect this may be the issue since the `!!! Failed Binder Transaction !!!` occured at this point in my debugging:

When I debug from this point

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

to this point

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

So clearly at these points I am passing data into a bundle.

So can anyone give me suggestions on how to get rid of the `Failed Binder Transaction`. Does this have to do with the Hashkey or Bundle? Or possibly something else?

**EDIT** logcat

```
01-06 15:59:34.240: D/SELinux(29917): selinux_knoxprecontexthook:  Calling  selinux_knoxprecontexthook for uid: 10244 isSystemServer: 0 seinfo: default pkgname com.example.androidfb20
01-06 15:59:34.250: D/dalvikvm(29917): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-06 15:59:34.400: D/AbsListView(29917): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-06 15:59:34.440: D/dalvikvm(29917): GC_CONCURRENT freed 288K, 8% free 18465K/19900K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 19ms
01-06 15:59:34.440: D/dalvikvm(29917): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-06 15:59:34.470: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 8
01-06 15:59:34.470: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:34.470: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-06 15:59:34.470: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:34.490: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-06 15:59:34.490: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:34.500: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:34.550: D/libEGL(29917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
01-06 15:59:34.550: D/libEGL(29917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
01-06 15:59:34.560: D/libEGL(29917): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  (CL3544079)
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): Build Date: 03/28/13 Thu
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): Local Branch: adreno_20130328
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): Remote Branch: 
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): Local Patches: 
01-06 15:59:34.560: I/Adreno200-EGL(29917): Reconstruct Branch: 
01-06 15:59:34.640: D/OpenGLRenderer(29917): Enabling debug mode 0
01-06 15:59:34.791: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:41.707: D/GestureDetector(29917): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
01-06 15:59:41.847: D/ProgressBar(29917): setProgress = 0
01-06 15:59:41.847: D/ProgressBar(29917): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
01-06 15:59:41.847: D/ProgressBar(29917): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 100
01-06 15:59:41.887: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:41.907: D/ProgressBar(29917): updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
01-06 15:59:41.907: D/ProgressBar(29917): updateDrawableBounds: top = 3
01-06 15:59:41.907: D/ProgressBar(29917): updateDrawableBounds: right = 144
01-06 15:59:41.907: D/ProgressBar(29917): updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 147
01-06 15:59:42.148: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
01-06 15:59:42.148: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:42.318: E/JavaBinder(29917): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
01-06 15:59:42.358: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-06 15:59:42.358: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:42.358: D/AbsListView(29917): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
01-06 15:59:42.358: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:42.358: I/endeffect(29917): AbsListView.onMeasure(), getWidth()=0, getHeight()=0, this=android.widget.ListView{4245b188 VFED.VC. .F....I. 0,0-0,0 #7f05006c app:id/selection_list}
01-06 15:59:42.398: D/dalvikvm(29917): GC_CONCURRENT freed 914K, 10% free 19520K/21580K, paused 5ms+2ms, total 38ms
01-06 15:59:42.408: D/dalvikvm(29917): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 15ms
01-06 15:59:42.408: I/dalvikvm-heap(29917): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.331MB for 160016-byte allocation
01-06 15:59:42.438: D/dalvikvm(29917): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 218K, 11% free 19458K/21740K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
01-06 15:59:42.468: D/dalvikvm(29917): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 11% free 19452K/21740K, paused 33ms, total 35ms
01-06 15:59:42.478: I/dalvikvm-heap(29917): Grow heap (frag case) to 21.485MB for 1440016-byte allocation
01-06 15:59:42.498: D/dalvikvm(29917): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 10% free 20857K/23148K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
01-06 15:59:42.508: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called 
01-06 15:59:42.508: I/endeffect(29917): AbsListView.onLayout(), getWidth()=960, getHeight()=240, this=android.widget.ListView{4245b188 VFED.VC. .F....ID 60,270-1020,510 #7f05006c app:id/selection_list}
01-06 15:59:42.648: D/AbsListView(29917): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Thanks

Comment: A "failed binder transaction" message usually comes from trying to send over 1MB of data across a standard IPC invocation. I don't use Facebook, let alone their SDK, and so I cannot give you specific advice. However, I would worry about large data being put in `onSaveInstanceState()`, in `Intent` extras, and the like. The stack trace associated with the "failed binder transaction" should give you more clues.

Comment: I updated my post with the logcat. Do you get enough information there to tell me what the issue is -- Is this what oyu mean by the stack trace? Please help :) I have been stuck on this for days..

Comment: No, I mean a Java stack trace, which you do not appear to have. You'll probably have to take this up with Facebook.

Comment: Ah there is no Exception when I run my application. It still runs but says Failed Binder Transaction in the logcat --- hm how do I contact Facebook to ask them about this issue...